# c# dictionary how to add data from a delimited list of strings with repeated values for a single keyinto a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list of strings in which each string contains delimiter separated values. There are many values that are being repeated so I need one key with multiple values

I Have already tried creating `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` but this does not work

Each string is  like

```
values = Man: rev
sum:2
Man: rev2
sum:2
```

values is a list of strings

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        foreach(var l in values)
        {
            var b = l.Split(':');
            var k = b.ElementAtOrDefault(0);

            if (!d.ContainsKey(k))
                d.Add(k, new List<string>());

            d[k].Add(l);
        }
```

When I try to search the dictionary using the method I mentioned above I am not able to retrieve the value for a particular key

Comment: Why are you splitting on `|`? Your example string doesn't contain `|`

Comment: In your example string, is 'Man' or 'rev' the key? Currently you're treating 'rev' as the key - is that correct?

Comment: `Dictionary<KeyType, valueCollectionType>`. For valueCollectionType the options include at least: string[], List[string], Tupels and structs with the proper fields. But the last two only work if oyu know the amount of values/string reliably. Pick your Poison.

Comment: You have given us the intended input. Now it would really help if you gave us the intended output/Dictionary format for this string. Otherwise it is really hard to guess how you intend to split that string.

Comment: Hi, I am splitting on :, wrote | by mistake.  the entire string is Man: Rev... so i wnt to make Man key and Rev its value

Comment: @Christopher I am not able to implement the option that you suggested since I am not able to add value from my list strings to it

Comment: "Hi, I am splitting on :, wrote | by mistake. the entire string is Man: Rev... so i wnt to make Man key and Rev its value" 1. That sounds very differnt from your original description. 2. Tht would give you two Rev and Man keys each, wich does not work. Please write down **exactly** how you want the resulting collection to look like. You can use the Dictionary Initializer syntax for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer

Comment: key: Man   value: Rev, Rev2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments provided I would suggest using the following construct (I can't test the code right now, but can fix it if needed):

```
Dictionary<string,string> result = values
   .Select(v => v.Split(new char[] {':'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .ToLookup(arr => arr.FirstOrDefault(), arr => String.Concat(arr.Skip(1))
   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => String.Join(", ", g.Select(i => i.Trim());
```

Explanation: first Select does the splitting; ToLookup creates the > structure using the first element as the key and the rest of the value string as the item (in the original question there was the whole string added - I'm not sure if that was the intention); ToDictionary then converts the List into a string (based on the comments as the desired output seems to be Distionary)

Comment: Hi @Marty But I am still not able to print the value for a particular. It gives keynotfound exception.

Comment: @rimakunj try to inspect the resulting Dictionary - e.g. just print out the keys together with values; or directly inspect them in the debug mode - there can be some extra whitespaces and that might be the reason, why you can't find the key. Alternatively edit your question and include also the exact way/code, how you are trying to print the value